# Getting sum of table fields values

Tags: mysql

I have student table contain Field : Value

```
firstname : John
lastname : Doe
english-grd : 87
math-grd : 80
science-grd : 85
total-grade : 0
```

My question is how I am going to get the fields with "-grd" only and sum there total.

Answer (score 2):

Query:

```
Select english-grd,math-grd,science-grd,(english-grd+math-grd+science-grd) as tot from table
```

Comment: What if I added another subject like pe_grd and I don't want to rewrite my code? I think this method is not going to work.

Comment: @arjay0601 - What you say is not possible and even doesn't seem to exist because if you add or remove a column in a table then you're modifying the internal structure of that table which is indeed not independent of the rest of the environment.

Comment: are you going to use php for this?

Comment: If you  will use php then you can take this (english-grd+math-grd+science-grd) in a variable before writing a query and in query put that variable.I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tableName set `total-grade` = (
`english-grd` + `math-grd` + `science-grd`
)
```

Comment: What if i added another subject like pe_grd and I want to sum it withour rewriting the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448192/can-a-mysql-select-statement-work-without-specifying-column-names

Answer (score 0):

```
// this example just update one row
$student_id = 1; // example only
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student where student_id='" . $student_id . "'");
$field_count = mysql_num_fields($res); //count field numbers
$total_grades = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $field_count; $i++)
{   
    $field_name=mysql_field_name($res, $i);
    if (substr($field_name,-4) == '-grd')
    {
        $total_grades = $total_grades + mysql_result($res,0,$i); // 0 refer to first row ...there is only one row from $res...$i is offset of the column
    }
}
mysql_query("update Student SET total-grade='" . $total_grades . "' where student_id='" . $student_id . "'");
```

Comment: For multiple rows you should fetch row number with `$table_rows  = mysql_num_rows($res);` and use another loop... I hope it works!